# Webscraping JS elements with Soup isnt working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm trying to use this python webscraper from this github but the website has changed slightly since the scraper was written so it doesn't work and I cant figure out why. https://github.com/heliphix/btc_data/blob/master/datacollector.py
In line 106:

```
values=soup.find_all('script')[5].get_text()
```

doesn't return anything from this webpage(https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/transactions-btc.html) like it should and I can't figure out why. I've fixed in my code which script it is going to because the site was updated it is now in the 4th script but even when I do

```
values=soup.find_all('script')[4].get_text()
```

It still returns nothing

```
values=soup.find_all('script')[4]
```

Dropping the .get_text() will return the section of code with the data in it but I don't know how to parse it from there.

I've tried using Simplified Scrapy to get the data from the JS function, but for some reason that doesn't work for all of the webpages.

Comment: 1) You should make it clear exactly what info should be returned. 2) There is surely a better dedicated API source for this type of info?

Comment: maybe they also change code in JavaScript and you need more changes  in your script.

Comment: What I see in that script tag does not look pleasant to parse back into a table and I would definitely look for an API

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, which data you want to extract but here as an example i tried to extract data using regex, requests and soup. I think there is a elegant way to extract data but i tried. Hope its help you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactions.html'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml').find_all('script')[4].string
# print(soup)
res = re.search(r'd = new Dygraph\(document.getElementById\(\"container\"\)\,(.*)ylabel',soup).groups(1)
script_4_data = res[0].split('{labels:')[0]

script_4_data = script_4_data[0:len(script_4_data)-2] # str type.
print(script_4_data) # list

# second step script 3

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find_all('script')[3].string
data = soup.split('{return',1)
# print(data)
bitcoin_data = data[1].split(';}var',1)[0]  # ok

print(bitcoin_data)
```